# Adding to Objects/Arrays

Tags: jquery

Im storing data in an object (because I want to convert it to json later).

```
var myObject = new Object();

myObject.name = "John";
myObject.name = "James";
```

I'm not too sure how this works because I want to sort of treat it like an array, being able to loop through and output each name

```
myObject[i]['name'];
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that like the way you did it. Try like this:

```
var myObjectNames = []; // means a new Array, or you can use: new Array() instead;
```

You can add new names like this:

```
myObjectNames.push("John");
myObjectNames.push("James");
```

Then output them all:

```
for(var x in myObjectNames) {
    console.log(myObjectNames[x]); // will output your names in the console
}
```

Or use join function:

```
console.log(myObjectNames.join(";")); // will output: "John;James" in the console
```

---

**EXTENDING THE ANSWER**

You can have the object:

```
var myObject = [];
```

Then just push the names into that array in `key->value` pairs:

```
var myNames = ['John', 'James', 'Zlatan'];

for(var x in myNames) {
    myObject.push({name: myNames[x]});
}

console.log(myObject);
```

There you will have the following structure in console output:

```
[Object { name=

"John"

}, Object { name=

"James"

}, Object { name=

"Zlatan"

}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an array of names, you can initialize myObject as an array and add the names to it, and add either by specifying the index or by using 'push'.

```
nameArray = []; //or new Array();
nameArray[0] = 'John';
nameArray.push('James');
```

The only thing about the above is that you can only store a single piece of information (i.e. you can store name, but not name and age)  If you want to store more than one you can create objects first with the properties you want, and then store them onto an array:

```
personArray = [];
person1= new Object();
person1.name = 'John';
person1.age = 18;
personArray.push(object1);
person2 = {}; //Shorter version of new Object()
person2.name = 'James';
person2.age = 31;
personArray.push(person2);
```

Then this can be accessed as desired:

```
personArray[1]['name']; //James
personArray[0].age; //18
```